# How to save a table to a file from Lua

Tags: io, lua

I'm having trouble printing a table to a file with lua (and I'm new to lua).

Here's some code [I found here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/09/02/tutorial-printing-table-contents/) to print the table;

```
function print_r ( t )  
    local print_r_cache={}
    local function sub_print_r(t,indent)
        if (print_r_cache[tostring(t)]) then
            print(indent.."*"..tostring(t))
        else
            print_r_cache[tostring(t)]=true
            if (type(t)=="table") then
                for pos,val in pairs(t) do
                    if (type(val)=="table") then
                        print(indent.."["..pos.."] => "..tostring(t).." {")
                        sub_print_r(val,indent..string.rep(" ",string.len(pos)+8))
                        print(indent..string.rep(" ",string.len(pos)+6).."}")
                    elseif (type(val)=="string") then
                        print(indent.."["..pos..'] => "'..val..'"')
                    else
                        print(indent.."["..pos.."] => "..tostring(val))
                    end
                end
            else
                print(indent..tostring(t))
            end
        end
    end
    if (type(t)=="table") then
        print(tostring(t).." {")
        sub_print_r(t,"  ")
        print("}")
    else
        sub_print_r(t,"  ")
    end
    print()
end
```

I have no idea where the 'print' command goes to, I'm running this lua code from within another program. What I would like to do is save the table to a .txt file. Here's what I've tried;

```
function savetxt ( t )
   local file = assert(io.open("C:\temp\test.txt", "w"))
   file:write(t)
   file:close()
end
```

Then in the print-r function I've changed everywhere it says 'print' to 'savetxt'. This doesn't work. It doesn't seem to access the text file in any way. Can anyone suggest an alternative method?

I have a suspicion that this line is the problem;

```
local file = assert(io.open("C:\temp\test.txt", "w"))
```

**Update;**
I have tried the edit suggested by [Diego Pino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134758/diego-pino) but still no success. I run this lua script from another program (for which I don't have the source), so I'm not sure where the default directory of the output file might be (is there a method to get this programatically?). Is is possible that since this is called from another program there's something blocking the output?

**Update #2;**
It seems like the problem is with this line:

```
   local file = assert(io.open("C:\test\test2.txt", "w"))
```

I've tried changing it "C:\temp\test2.text", but that didn't work. I'm pretty confident it's an error at this point. If I comment out any line after this (but leave this line in) then it still fails, if I comment out this line (and any following 'file' lines) then the code runs. What could be causing this error?

Comment: As a follow up question; where do files get created if I don't specify the directory (which seems to be what's done in all the tutorials)?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile

Comment: `io.open("C:\temp\test.txt", "w")` opens not what you think.

Comment: @moteus what do you mean?

Comment: "\t" is tab. try "\\t". Also to save data in file you can just use some existed serialize library json/msgpack/cbor/serpent etc. Why need write new one?

Comment: I've tried the \\t - still fails. Can I include serialised library in a single lua file that gets call from a program that I have no control over?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg Here is a gist with the full code https://gist.github.com/dpino/af37d70554d157bbee289f489945cce5 I run it and it seems to work well. Perhaps as you said it's an issue related with the path filename (does C:\test folder exist?).

Answer (score 3):

Your `print_r` function prints out a table to *stdout*. What you want is to print out the output of `print_r` to a file. Change the `print_r` function so instead of printing to stdout, it prints out to a file descriptor. Perhaps the easiest way to do that is to pass a file descriptor to `print_r` and overwrite the `print` function:

```
function print_r (t, fd)
    fd = fd or io.stdout
    local function print(str)
       str = str or ""
       fd:write(str.."\n")
    end
    ...
end
```

The rest of the `print_r` doesn't need any change.

Later in `savetxt` call `print_r` to print the table to a file.

```
function savetxt (t)
   local file = assert(io.open("C:\temp\test.txt", "w"))
   print_r(t, file)
   file:close()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea where the 'print' command goes to,

print() output goes to default output file, you can change that with io.output([file]), see Lua manuals for details on querying and changing default output.

> where do files get created if I don't specify the directory

Typically it will land in current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

1. 

```
require("json")
result = {
    ["ip"]="192.168.0.177",
    ["date"]="2018-1-21",
}

local test = assert(io.open("/tmp/abc.txt", "w"))
result = json.encode(result)
test:write(result)
test:close()

local test = io.open("/tmp/abc.txt", "r")
local readjson= test:read("*a")
local table =json.decode(readjson)
test:close()

print("ip: " .. table["ip"])
```

2.Another way：
http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile

Save Table to File
function table.save(  tbl,filename )

Load Table from File
function table.load( sfile )